# How to split a dataframe according to a boolean criterion?

Tags: pandas

Suppose that `df` is a `pandas` dataframe.  I want to split it into two dataframes according to some criterion.  The best way I've found for doing this is something like

```
df0, df1 = [v for _, v in df.groupby(df['class'] != 'special')]
```

In the above example, the criterion is the argument to the `groupby` method.  The resulting `df0` consists of the sub-dataframe where the `class` field *has* value `'special'`, and `df1` is basically the complement of `df0`.  (Unfortunately, with this construct, the sub-dataframe consisting of the items that *fail* the criterion are returned first, which is not intuitive.)

The above construct has the drawback that it is not particularly readable, certainly not as readable as, for instance, some hypothetical `splitby` method like

```
df0, df1 = df.splitby(df['class'] == 'special')
```

Since splitting a dataframe like this is something I often need to do, I figure that there may be a built-in function, or maybe an established idiom, for doing this.  If so, please let me know.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think the most readable way is to do this is:

```
m = df['class'] != 'special'
a, b = df[m], df[~m]
```

*I haven't come across a special method for this...*

Comment: I might do `d = dict(list(df.groupby(df["class"] != "b")))` and then use `d[0]`/`d[False]` and `d[1]`/`d[True]` instead.

Comment: @DSM In fact, groupby is probably an even better way to store it (!)

Comment: @AndyHayden: what do you mean? It would be great if one could just address the content of groupby by its (pseudo-)keys, but it doesn't work; i.e. `df.groupby(df.class != 'b')[True]` throws an error...  I don't know how to do this sort of thing without converting the groupby object to a dict...

Comment: But what I mean to say is, why convert to a dict when you can access via `g.get_group(True)` ?